# Android Crash tracking on apps that are not on Google Play

Tags: android, crash-reports

I'm looking for a way to track crashes in an app that I am not uploading to Google Play.

I've read about [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) but it seems that it would take time to get the sdk.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have implemented crash reporting, which enable users to send crash report via email. Is this something you are interested in!!

Comment: I use Deploygate, very easy to get it going.

Comment: This question is off-topic, and I've marked it as such. However, it's not too difficult to find ACRA, Flurry, Crashlytics et al, is it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice api name "Bugsense" to trap all your app crashes. It is very simple to use. Crash report will be sent on your mail whenever you get exception. Register your app on following link to get key:

https://mint.splunk.com/

You have to build jar file and include the key in onCreate of your MainActivity :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);


BugSenseHandler.setup(this, "YOUR_API_KEY");


// The rest of your code goes here

}
```